# Strange issue with OpenCV warpPerspective function on Android

Tags: android, opencv

In order to improve my Android App, I  tried to test warpPerspective performance on my mobile phone by warp a image with 640*480 size to different size . The result is weird as following :
[image: The cost time is the total time of 100 times warp function. Each size was warped three times.]

I thought the time is direct proportion with the wrapped size, But it was not ,as we can see from the picture 640*480 -> 360*270 cost maximum time.

Any explanation will be appreciated . Thx~